# Negative lookahead not working

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to fix a text file with regex using sublime

the text has instances of

```
.. "description": "some description", "address": "some address", ...
```

for some reason I have instances that look like

```
.. "description": "some description", "some address", ...
```

So I want to find those faulty ones and insert `"address":` to it.

I am trying to do this with negative lookahead with

```
\"description\":\s*\".*?\"\,\s*(?!\"address\"\:)
```

but it finds every instances, and not only the `description` not followed by `address`

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Good thing this isn't a sublime text bug, or it'll never be fixed! You had me scared there for a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your pattern is the last `\s*` before the negative-look ahead is throwing the pattern off, try this instead

```
(\"description\":\s*\"[^"]*\"\,)(?!\s?\"address\"\:)
```

and replace with `$1"address":`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/60)

```
(                   Capturing Group \1
  \"                """
  description           "description"
  \"                """
  :                 ":"
  \s                <whitespace character>
  *                 (zero or more)(greedy)
  \"                """
  [^"]              Character not in [^"]
  *                 (zero or more)(greedy)
  \"                """
  \,                ","
)                   End of Capturing Group \1
(?!                 Negative Look-Ahead
  \s                <whitespace character>
  ?                 (zero or one)(greedy)
  \"                """
  address               "address"
  \"                """
  \:                ":"
)                   End of Negative Look-Ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for this regex:

```
("description":\s*"[^"]*\"\s*,\s*")(?!address")([^"]*".*$)
```

And replace by:

```
$1address": "$2
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aS9mB2/1)